# Folder Size in Document Libraries

Tags: document-library

I am trying to figure out the size of a folder within a document library to help keep tabs on how big the teamsite is getting. I am doing this by modifying the view, then going to Totals>Folder Size> Sum and Name>Count

I would expect for a line at the top of the library to then "sum" the numbers in the 'File Size' column, but nothing appears up there. Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: See: _layouts/15/storman.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, there is not column called `Folder Size`, it's `File size`, and to be able to apply the `sum function`. the `File size` should be selected to show as a column in the view.

Steps to show Sum files size

- Open your library > from the above ribbon > Click on Modify view.
- In the column section, select File size.
- In totals section select file size and sum.

[image]

- Now the file size should be shown as below.

[image]

**Note**: To show the `File size` of a folder, you should be inside this folder, and if you have subfolders inside the main folder it will not be calculated in the total of the main folder.and this case you can open your library **via explorer** from the above ribbon and check the properties of this folder.

**Note:** In modern Mode, the Total is not available. it's only available in classic mode.

Comment: Thank you. Apologies for the typo, I am summing the "File Size" column. However, my lists are using the new view, and that sum number isn't showing up on top. Do you know if the old/new list view could impact this? Is there an equivalent to the "explorer" in modern view? Also - I would like this to be for a folder that contains another folder, not the bottom level folder.

Comment: Yes if you are on modern list view you probably won't see this. It works only with the classic view.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add for future Googlers, the custom view didn't work for me as it only sums up files in the folder, and doesn't do any recursive sums. But [Tim](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/71131/tim)'s comment on the OP's question was helpful for me, and may be helpful for others who end up here.

---

**As of 2021/08/26:** Storage Metrics can be found by going to `Site contents (from left sidebar of a Sharepoint Site) > Site settings > Site Collection Administration > Storage Metrics`

---

Original:

The Site Settings > Storage Metrics section shows a recursive total size for folders and libraries. Apparently Microsoft removed the navigation path from Site Settings, as all paths on Googled answers don't exist anymore. But using Tim's hint above I found the full URL to be:

`https://*your-subdomain*.sharepoint.com/sites/Files/_layouts/15/storman.aspx`

Similarly, you can get there from Office Admin Center:

1. Go to O365 Admin Center
2. On left sidebar navigate to SharePoint Admin Center
3. In SharePoint Admin Center left nav, go to Sites > Active Sites

The direct URL for this one is:

`https://*your-admin-subdomain*.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/online/AdminHome.aspx#/siteManagement/view/ALL%20SITES`